# EntityFramework inclusion via NuGet confusion

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

I'm getting myself really confused after including EntityFramework via NuGet. So I've created a project called **CustomModules** and inside here I've got my database context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<FreightCompany> Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<FuelSurcharge> FuelSurcharges { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<ZoneMapping> ZoneMappings { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<ShippingRate> ShippingRates { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Markup> Markups { get; set; }
}
```

I've enabled migrations and all this has been pushed into the database just fine. I now want to use consume this in a web application. I've therefore copied the connection string from the **CustomModules.appconfig** to my **CMSApp.webconfig**.

At this point I've tried to use an EntityDataSource on an ASPX page and found that I had no named containers to choose from.

[image]

So I've been reading all sorts and come across the fact that there's 2 types of connection string. A typical ADO one and an entity framework one. I believe I've just got the ADO one:

```
<add name="Context" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;database=DS_Kentico;server=SERVER;user id=USER;password=PWD;Current Language=English;Connection Timeout=240;" />
```

So I've read about the Entity Framework one and the ways of generating one which suggests using the Entity Framework designer attached to the EDMX file. But I have no EDMX file. So I'm confused as to whether I've got myself into some crazy state somehow or if it's normal to not have an EDMX file?

Ultimately how do I go about creating an Entity Framework connection string, that correctly uses anything it needs (Context etc) from the DLL which I reference?

**edit**

I should also add that I don't see to have any of the csdl, ssdl files that seem to get commonly referenced in these strings...

Comment: When you use Code First there are no model files. The classes and context are your models. So yes, it's normal there's no model files. So the problem must have to do with references or accesibility (public vs private) of your entities or contexts. What happens if you conpy your context file with one or two of the classes to the web app project? Can you use it in that case?

Comment: @JotaBe: Thanks. I believe I found the answer today, and that is that you can't use the configuration. Instead there's a different way to bind when using CodeFirst.

Answer (score 0):

To use the code first approach you need to write the connection-string in a different way (assuming that the use LocalDb and the MDF file would be attached to your App_Data solution's folder):

```
   <add name="SomeContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|\YOURNAME.mdf;Initial Catalog=YOURNAME;Integrated Security=SSPI"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

If your connection string is different from the EF convention (Context), you'll need to pass the connection string value through a parameter on the DbContext base constructor:

```
public FinappDb(): base("MyDbConnString") { } /* It is not like the convention */
```

You'll also need to configure the Connection Factory for localDb:

```
  <entityFramework>
     <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Your database shoul be created by the first time you create your DbContext class from your code (until that the DB will not be created).